# Using AChartEngine library for graphs, not able to get value for diffrent x-axis value

Tags: android, achartengine

```
public static ArrayList<double[]> Value = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    private double[] x = new double[10];
    private double[] y = new double[10];
    int counter = -1;

add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                x[counter] = Double.parseDouble(income_1.getText().toString());
                y[counter] = Double.parseDouble(income_2.getText().toString());
                income_1.setText("");
                income_2.setText("");
            }
        });

publish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Value != null) {
                    Value.add(x);
                    Value.add(y);
                    Intent intent = salesStackedBarChart.execute(BarChart.this,
                            Value, counter);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });


//and in SalesStackedBarChart.java class

public Intent execute(Context context, ArrayList<double[]> values ,int counter) {
        int count = counter + 1;
        double fcount = counter + 1.5;
        String[] titles = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone" };
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Yearly revenue in the last "+count+" years", "Years", "revenue in $", 0.5,
                fcount, 0, 24000, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
        renderer.setXLabels(count);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
        return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,
            Type.DEFAULT);
      }

// in AbstractDemoChart.java class

 protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    int length = titles.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
      double[] v = values.get(i);
      int seriesLength = v.length;
      for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
        series.add(v[k]);
      }
      dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    }
    return dataset;
  }
```

Run this project i get graph with x- axis value:

```
1,2,3,4,5....
```

But I want to print value:

```
2005,2006,2007,2008.....
```

I changed in some code like:

```
setChartSettings(renderer, "Yearly revenue in the last "+count+" years", "Years", "revenue in $", 2005,
                2010, 0, 24000, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
```

and  run project i get value of x-axis like:

```
2005,2006,2007....
```

but not get graph bar value. Values of all x-axis are null. How can I make this work?
    [image: x-axis value 1,2,3...]

[image: when change x-axis value 2006,2007,....]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public static ArrayList<double[]> Value = new ArrayList<double[]>();`
 `private double[] x = new double[2010];`
`private double[] y = new double[2010];`
 `int counter = 2005;`

Answer (score 0):

i have done it this way:

```
xScale = 5;    
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i = 0; i < this.xScale; i++) {
        Calendar c = (Calendar) today.clone();
        c.set(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DATE) - (this.xScale - (i + 1)));
        x.get(0)[i] = new Date(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900, c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE));
        x.get(1)[i] = new Date(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900, c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE));
}
```

this shows you the last 5 days an the x axis