# Achartengine: Inserting dates as X-values in

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine to display averages across several days (2 months if possible). I'd like to provide a comparison between one individual and a group. At this point, I'm working on how to provide dates across the x-axis (ie, 12/15/2011 or Dec. 11, 2011 or even 12/15, Dec. 15).

I'm not sure how to do this in AchartEngine; the documentation is a little hard for me to follow without pictures (sorry). I'd like something like this: [Using AChartEngine library for graphs, not able to get value for diffrent x-axis value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689178/using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-not-able-to-get-value-for-diffrent-x-axis)

Here's my code:

```
private void setupHistoryChart() {    
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getBarDemoRenderer();
        setChartSettings(renderer);
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, getBarDemoDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

     public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarDemoRenderer() {
         XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
         renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
         renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(18);
         renderer.setLabelsTextSize(12);
         renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
         renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
         SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
         r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

         return renderer;
       }

     private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {   
         renderer.setChartTitle("History");
         renderer.setChartTitleTextSize((float) 14.0);
         renderer.setXTitle("Day");
         renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
         renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
         renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
         renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
         renderer.setZoomRate(0.2f);
         renderer.setYTitle("Unit)");
         renderer.setXAxisMin(1.0);

         if(AppStatus.mDayMap.size() == 0){
             renderer.setXAxisMax(3.0);
             renderer.setYAxisMax(10.0);
         }else{
             renderer.setXAxisMax(AppStatus.mDayMap.size());
             // Get the max Integer out of myMap
             Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;

             for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : AppStatus.mDayMap.entrySet())
             {
                 if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
                 {
                     maxEntry = entry;
                 }
             }
             renderer.setYAxisMax(maxEntry.getValue()/1000 + maxEntry.getValue()/1000);
         }
         renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
       }

     private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDemoDataset() {
         XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
         HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = AppStatus.mDayMap;
         CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries ("Your History " + 1);
         try{

             if(AppStatus.mDayMap.size() == 0){
                 series.add(3.0);
                 series.add(10.0);
                 dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
             }else{
                 Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Size of Map = " + myMap.size());
                 float sum = (float) 0.0;
                 if(myMap.size() > 0){
                     Iterator it = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
                     float j= (float)0.0;
                     for (int i = 0; i < 1 /*2*/; i++) {
                       //CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Your History " + (i + 1));
                       while(it.hasNext()){
                           Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                           sum = sum + (float) (1.0 + j);
                           series.add((((Integer) pairs.getValue()).doubleValue())/1000); 
                       }
                       dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
                     }
                 }
             }

         }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
             Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IllegalArgumentException " + e.toString());
             series.add(3.0);
             series.add(10.0);
             dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
         }

         return dataset;
       }
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set custom text for the X axis labels:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, text);
renderer.setXLabels(0);
```

In order to have multiple color bars in the bar chart, you will have to add multiple series.

There are some instructions [here](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html) on how to download and run the demo application which includes a lot of good code to demonstrate the AChartEngine usage.